How market maker activity in the options markets effect the stock market
So from what I understand,when there is a large demand for call options ,the MMs that sell the options see this large demand for it, so they hedge by actually buying the underlying stock . Because after all the marker maker takes both sides of a trade when they "make the market" so if there is a large demand for call options it will usually mean only one side of their orders get filled so they lose inventory and are also making a loss which is why they hedge with the actually stock .
However, I was reading online more about this when I came across this paragraph -----> "One of the primary indicators of market maker activity is trading volume. An unusual spike in volume, particularly in options markets, can often precede large moves in stock prices. For instance, if a market maker accumulates a significant position in call options, it may signal their anticipation of an upward price movement."
Now this was slightly confusing, as while a spike in the volume of the amount of call options being bought can be a precursor of the actually stock price increasing ,since retail traders may see this as a bullish sign for the stock itself so they buy the stock and the MM's buy the stock to hedge ...... the paragraph however says when a Market Maker accumulates a significant position in call options it may signal an increase in price upcoming for the stock.
This confuses me , while the market maker profits from market-making spreads ,its main goal is to provide liquidity so it's on both sides of the trade so it isn't betting on significant directional movements to happen, that's what its avoiding. The only real way I see a market maker accumulating call options is if loads of people are selling their call options so the price of the options goes down which means that only one side of the market maker position gets filled (bid) hence why they are accumulating call options ... but if anything this would signal a decrease in stock price.
The paragraph almost makes it seem like the market maker is trading like a normal retail trader and betting on a price direction ,when in reality if there is a significant demand increase in call options it is unlikely to be the market maker.

Is it possible that you are assuming that the large call positions accumulated by MMs are long positions.  The MM can also accumulate large call position by writing call options to meet demand.  They would then buy the underlying stock to manage the risk of being "called away" and having to deliver stock.

@not-nick when they say "a market maker accumulates a significant position in call options, it may signal their anticipation of an upward price movement." ,I can only assume this means that the MM is buying call options not selling , because surely if the MM anticipates upward price movement they know that only the sell side of their call options will be filled .I know "position" could be both buy or sell ,but if the MM is anticipating upward price movement how do they react to that?


Designated Market Makers can trade for their own account in the securities they are assigned to trade.  2) For every transaction, there's a buyer and a seller.  One is bullish and one is bearish.  If the MM owns the calls, what makes you think he can only be bullish?  Suppose that there was a large put seller.  The MM could have executed a reversal by buying the call and shorting the stock and the put. He is then net neutral, profiting from the arbitrage.  The put buyer and the call seller have the directional risk.


i wasnt saying that the MM was bullish ,i was saying the opposite ie that MM don't make markets based on directional movements .However the  paragraph I quoted made it seem like the MM was taking on  call option positions in anticipation of an increase price .


Yes, MMs don't make markets based on directional movements but they do trade for their own accounts so they can be directional.  2) "For instance, if a market maker accumulates a significant position in call options, it may signal their anticipation of an upward price movement."  Umm, isn't that the definition of being bullish, taking a long position in anticipation of a upward move?

